# Nested routes and outlets within outlets

Tags: ember.js

This could be a rather trivial question, but as an Ember beginner, I am struggling with it a bit.

The site I'm building has a parent navigation, but some of the templates inside its outlet may have their own navigation and their own outlet (at least that's what I'm intending). In other words, I might have something like (skipping a lot of HTML):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to 'testing'}}Testing{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>{{outlet}}{/div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="testing">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>{{#link-to 'testing.encoding'}}Encoding{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to 'testing.user'}}User Admin{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div>{{outlet}}{/div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="testing/encoding">
    <h3>Encoding</h3>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="testing/user">
    <h3>User Admin</h3>
</script>
```

The application template wires great. Click on "Home", you get the `index` template; click on "Testing", you get the `testing` template. Super. What I want is for when they click "Encoding", the route is then /testing/encoding and the `testing/encoding` template is rendered in the outlet inside of `testing`. My Router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('testing', function() {
        this.route('encoding');
        this.route('users');
    });
});
```

However, the page won't load at all, giving me: `Uncaught Error: There is no route named encoding.index`. I suspect I named my templates poorly, or configured my Router incorrectly, or perhaps need to name the `outlet` in the `testing` template... and I've attacked those potential issues, but have yet to come up with a resolution.

Ideas? This is probably a typical pattern and likely has a clean, easy solution with minimal javascript. I'm just not seeing it, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your router to look like this.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('testing', function() {
        this.route('encoding');
        this.route('users');
    });
});
```

You can't nest a route under a route. What you get with the resource is the leaf routes of index, loading and error.

There is not route `encoding.index` in this router.

The [routing guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) here is really helpful.

Cheers

Comment: Gah. Could've sworn I tried that. Guess not; just tried it again and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For one you didn't name your route correctly (it should be `this.route('encoding');` instead of `this.route('encode');`. But the bigger issue is that Ember doesn't allow for nested routes, only nested resources (and routes nested in resources).

[The Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources) say: "*You cannot nest routes, but you can nest resources.*"